# Need help resolving JavaScript heap out of memory error when running npm run build

Tags: node.js, npm

I have tried multiple fixes found around the forums and other who asked the same question. None seem to be working for me.

I am on Windows 10. Latest stable Node release - 14.17.6, npm 6.14.15. I tried adding a new environment and setting it to 16gb. Tried using node --max-old-space-size=4096 index.js (I attempted various memory sizes none seemed to work. I fresh installed Node, npm, and yarn. I have 32gb of system memory, before attempting the build about 5gb are in use.

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[22084:0000018BDBF7ACD0]   115116 ms: Scavenge 32.7 (37.6) -> 32.4 (38.1) MB, 24.2 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.998, current mu = 0.998) allocation failure
[22084:0000018BDBF7ACD0]   115136 ms: Scavenge 32.4 (38.1) -> 32.4 (38.6) MB, 20.0 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.998, current mu = 0.998) allocation failure
[22084:0000018BDBF7ACD0]   115154 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 32.4 (38.6) -> 32.2 (38.1) MB, 17.8 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.978, current mu = 0.929) last resort GC in old space requested

<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: Committing semi space failed. Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 00007FF6593D4C9F
 2: 00007FF659378226
 3: 00007FF659379126
 4: 00007FF659C52ABE
 5: 00007FF659C3788D
 6: 00007FF659AE09DC
 7: 00007FF659AE8F9F
 8: 00007FF659ADDAD1
 9: 00007FF659ADCB42
10: 00007FF659ADBD55
11: 00007FF659AF5B65
12: 00007FF659AF5FB5
13: 00007FF659B09AF6
14: 00007FF659B0557A
15: 00007FF6599CA9A0
16: 00007FF659853F87
17: 00007FF659CDB97D
18: 000001F1E2E4F809
```

`Code`

```
const fs = require("fs");
const { createCanvas, loadImage } = require("canvas");
const console = require("console");
const { layersOrder, format, rarity } = require("./config.js");

const canvas = createCanvas(format.width, format.height);
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

if (!process.env.PWD) {
  process.env.PWD = process.cwd();
}

const buildDir = `${process.env.PWD}/build`;
const metDataFile = '_metadata.json';
const layersDir = `${process.env.PWD}/layers`;

let metadata = [];
let attributes = [];
let hash = [];
let decodedHash = [];

const addRarity = _str => {
  let itemRarity;

  rarity.forEach((r) => {
    if (_str.includes(r.key)) {
      itemRarity = r.val;
    }
  });

  return itemRarity;
};

const cleanName = _str => {
  let name = _str.slice(0, -4);
  rarity.forEach((r) => {
    name = name.replace(r.key, "");
  });
  return name;
};

const getElements = path => {
  return fs
    .readdirSync(path)
    .filter((item) => !/(^|\/)\.[^\/\.]/g.test(item))
    .map((i, index) => {
      return {
        id: index + 1,
        name: cleanName(i),
        fileName: i.trim(),
        rarity: addRarity(i),
      };
    });
};

const layersSetup = layersOrder => {
  const layers = layersOrder.map((layer, index) => ({
    id: index,
    name: layer,
    location: `${layersDir}/${layer}/`,
    elements: getElements(`${layersDir}/${layer}/`),
    position: { x: 0, y: 0 },
    size: { width: format.width, height: format.height },
  }));

  return layers;
};

const buildSetup = () => {
  if (fs.existsSync(buildDir)) {
    fs.rmdirSync(buildDir, { recursive: true });
  }
  fs.mkdirSync(buildDir);
};

const saveLayer = (_canvas, _edition) => {
  fs.writeFileSync(`${buildDir}/${_edition}.png`, _canvas.toBuffer("image/png"));
};

const addMetadata = _edition => {
  let tempMetadata = {
    name:`Loothereum Chest #${_edition}`,
    image:'ADD_IMAGES_BASE_URI_HERE0.png',
    description:'EDIT THIS',
    tokenId:_edition,
    attributes: attributes.map(attribute=>{
      return {
        trait_type:attribute.layer,
        value:attribute.name
      }
    })
  };
  metadata.push(tempMetadata);
  attributes = [];
  hash = [];
  decodedHash = [];
};

const addAttributes = (_element, _layer) => {
  let tempAttr = {
    id: _element.id,
    layer: _layer.name,
    name: _element.name,
    rarity: _element.rarity,
  };
  attributes.push(tempAttr);
  hash.push(_layer.id);
  hash.push(_element.id);
  decodedHash.push({ [_layer.id]: _element.id });
};

const drawLayer = async (_layer, _edition) => {
  let element =
    _layer.elements[Math.floor(Math.random() * _layer.elements.length)];
  addAttributes(element, _layer);
  console.log(_layer.location,element.fileName)
  const image = await loadImage(`${_layer.location}${element.fileName}`);

  ctx.drawImage(
    image,
    _layer.position.x,
    _layer.position.y,
    _layer.size.width,
    _layer.size.height
  );
  saveLayer(canvas, _edition);
};

const createFiles = edition => {
  const layers = layersSetup(layersOrder);

  for (let i = 1; i <= edition; i++) {
    layers.forEach((layer) => {
      drawLayer(layer, i);
    });
    addMetadata(i);
    console.log("Creating edition " + i);
  }
};

const createMetaData = () => {
  fs.stat(`${buildDir}/${metDataFile}`, (err) => {
    if(err == null || err.code === 'ENOENT') {
      fs.writeFileSync(`${buildDir}/${metDataFile}`, JSON.stringify(metadata));
    } else {
        console.log('Oh no, error: ', err.code);
    }
  });
};

module.exports = { buildSetup, createFiles, createMetaData };
```

Comment: Can you show us your code please, because this is likely an issue with your code and not with your machine?

Comment: the build runs fine when i lower the generation amount to around 4k on my machine. My business partner runs the full build just fine on his pc

Comment: I will echo @Ameer here and ask for code. We won't be able to help you otherwise.

Comment: sorry, i dont post much on here. Can I attach the file here, or copy the code directly

Comment: You can copy and paste the code directly @mrhexxx, please only add the relavent code so it's easier for us to find the problem!

Comment: updated post, that is the main.js file from the build

Comment: it generates png's with layer images from another folder. i can get it to about 4k, but anymore and it crashes. on a different PC it can do well over 7k and work fine.